# how to validate a string with a basic code in python

Tags: python, string, validation

I need to know how to check if a string only contains letters.

example:

```
name=input("enter your name \n")
    while len(name) < 2:
    name=input("please enter a valid name \n")
```

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.isalpha()`

```
>>> 'abc'.isalpha()
True
>>> 'abc12'.isalpha()
False
```

Or if you are expecting a first and last name, and want to ignore the space separator

```
>>> 'foo bar'.replace(' ', '').isalpha()
True
```